# Smart search and replace in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, bash, scripting

I created a preprocessor symbol in Xcode that releases a variable and sets it to nil like this:

```
#define ReleaseAndSetToNil(x) [x release]; x = nil;
```

However now that I want to ARC my project, this macro is problematic. Therefore, I'd like to replace all occurrences of the macro in my project (hundreds) to corresponding release and nil statements. Is there a way I can do this in Xcode?

Basically , I'd like to search for:

```
ReleaseAndSetToNil(whatever)
```

... and replace it with:

```
[whatever release]; 
whatever = nil;
```

Is there a script I can use for this?

Comment: you can try viewing preprocessed code for files in question. You'd see `ReleaseAndSetToNil(x)` replaced with `[x release]; x = nil;`

Answer (score 2):

If you are converting to ARC, why don't you just modify the macro to `#define ReleaseAndSetToNil(x) x = nil;`?

In your existing code, after switching to ARC, this will be essentially the same.